# Stored value not being set to nil when user deselects all options - rails / simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

I have the following form input which is working, except for one small 'bug'

```
<%= f.input :secondary_role, :collection => UseridRole::VALUES, :include_blank => false,:label => "Secondary Role(s):", :input_html => {  :class => " simple_form_bgcolour simple_form_position overide_selection_field_width", :size => 4, multiple: true }, include_hidden: false, :hint => "Hold shift to select multiple roles" %>
```

My user's secondary role is stored in my DB as an array:-

```
"secondary_role": ["moderator"]
```

My problem is that in cases where the user has set a secondary role, that can't be un-set by deselecting the option.  Nothing happens when an option is deselected in the list and saved.  The above moderator can only be removed by selecting another option.  How can I make the array empty upon deselection of all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `include_hidden: false` option; the hidden field is there to make this work automatically.

(Otherwise, you'll need to handle the situation manually in the controller action that receives the form submission.)

Comment: Ah - well that little snippet gave me another issue here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51341912/empty-array-value-being-input-with-simple-form-entries

Comment: So I'll probably have to handle it in the controller, though I thought best practice was to put any logic into your models?

Comment: Data logic belongs in the model, but this is a communication/collaboration issue, which is the realm of the controller: without the hidden option, there is no direct cue that the form contained a select-multiple field at all; if the controller knows that there was one there (and therefore the lack of a value is significant), it is its job to fill that in.

Comment: That makes sense. The codebase I'm working with doesn't seem to be following this practice though...  I've added the method below in my other post, into my user model, and is easily called with the existing callbacks in the model (before_save).  How would you go about calling this method if it lived in the controller as you suggested? Sorry for all the questions!

Answer (score 0):

So as @matthewd pointed out, the solution was to remove the `include_hidden: false` option, although this introduced another issue of a blank array item being added to my roles array.

So, I added the below method to trigger before every save and remove any blank array entries:

```
  def remove_blank_entry
    secondary_role = self.secondary_role
    if secondary_role.include? ""
      secondary_role.delete("")
    end
  end
```

Comment: you can use the `reject` method to clean this up: `secondary_role.reject(&:blank?)`